# NotImplementedError in pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I was trying to read the data from Yahoo Finance but I am getting an error.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as data
```

Here's the cell where I am getting the error:

```
start = '2012-01-01' 
end = '2021-12-31'

df = data.DataReader('AAPL', start, end)
```

This is the error message I am encountering:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d022432a6feb> in <module>()
      2 end = '2021-12-31'
      3 
----> 4 df = data.DataReader('AAPL', start, end)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    371     if data_source not in expected_source:
    372         msg = "data_source=%r is not implemented" % data_source
--> 373         raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    374 
    375     if data_source == "yahoo":

NotImplementedError: data_source='2012-01-01' is not implemented
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: What's your interpretation of the error? How should the library interpret `data_source='2012-01-01'`?

Comment: https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance-data

Comment: I didn't get your question, can you please brief me?

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error message: `NotImplementedError: data_source='2012-01-01' is not implemented` ?

Comment: Here's the link to colab notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JNz4K4DN1dMYK5o9DKBP2B7QlMECKroA?usp=sharing

You can review it for clarity

Comment: I'm not asking to see your notebook. I'm asking you to read that error and explain what you think it means. I also provided a link to the documentation for the function. I think you should read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start = '2012-01-01', end = '2021-12-31')
```

Output

```
                  High         Low  ...       Volume   Adj Close
Date                                ...                         
2012-01-03   14.732143   14.607143  ...  302220800.0   12.575914
2012-01-04   14.810000   14.617143  ...  260022000.0   12.643499
2012-01-05   14.948214   14.738214  ...  271269600.0   12.783866
2012-01-06   15.098214   14.972143  ...  318292800.0   12.917505
2012-01-09   15.276786   15.048214  ...  394024400.0   12.897019
```

No data source specified: 'yahoo'

Comment: Hey thanks @inquirer for the help the previous error ha s been resolved. But now I'm encountering a remote data error saying, it cannot fetch data from yahoo finance.

`RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1641009599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history`

Comment: Show how you make the request.